# How to add css class to an element with EventListener

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I am trying to change the class of some element to do a variable element (like classic/plus/premium).

I already setup 3 buttons with the ID : classic-button, plus-button and premium-button.

Here is my code for JavaScript :

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("classic-button").addEventListener('click',function ()
    {
        $('#classic-price').addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
    }  ); 

    document.getElementById("plus-button").addEventListener('click',function ()
    {
        $('#plus-price').addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
    }  ); 

    document.getElementById("premium-button").addEventListener('click',function ()
    {
        $('#premium-price').addClass('show').removeClass('hide')
        console.log("salut ça marche")
    }  ); 
});
</script>
```

And I want my elements #***-price to appear when I click on its button.

Here's my CSS class for hide and show :

```
.show{
    visibility:visible;
    position:static;
}
.hide{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I must add that I can't add onclick attribute in my button because it is not properly a button.

But my console told me that `$('#plus-price').addClass('show').removeClass('hide')` is not a function, what am I supposed to do?

Comment: missing semicolon after `removeClass('hide')`?

Comment: U were right finally thank you !

Comment: I meant all three occurances

Comment: Not an answer but some advice: You don't need both "hide" and "show", you can do this with just one class and it makes it simpler. Pick a "default" state — are things normally showing, or normally hiding? Let's say things are hidden normally, until something is clicked. Have `div.thing { display: none; }` and `div.thing.showing { display: block; }` Then when clicked you just _add_ class "showing" — no need to _also_ remove the "hide" class.

Comment: Normally only one table appears and then ths user can change it, I took notes for your advice thank you, and for correcting too I am not english

Comment: @StephenP But then you're required to add those classes to every element on the page, which means that you'd need to use `*{ }` or something similar, and it also means that you would be crazy to not pick showing as the default.......

Comment: @OOPSStudio - I don't think you'd be adding those classes to every element, but maybe I don't understand the structure, because OP doesn't include any markup demonstrating the structure. But if you wanted things hidden until click you'd definitely _not_ want showing as the default... "things of class 'thing' are display:none until/unless they are marked as 'showing'" — but we're debating a hypothetical.

Comment: @StephenP Maybe I missunderstood you but I have to show only one table, it's a price table, so the user can choose his package and the one he choose appears instead of the other, so you're right I have to hide the others in the same code if I want only one table.
I'll try to create another code to do as you say because mine don't work anyway then I'll ask if I have a problem, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thats your code with added missing semicolons. Click on the Classic Button ;)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.getElementById("classic-button").addEventListener('click',function (e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
       jQuery('#classic-price').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
    }  ); 

    document.getElementById("plus-button").addEventListener('click',function ()
    {
        jQuery('#plus-price').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
    }  ); 

    document.getElementById("premium-button").addEventListener('click',function () {
        jQuery('#premium-price').addClass('show').removeClass('hide');
        console.log("salut ça marche");
    }  ); 
});
```

```css
.show{
    visibility:visible;
    position:static;
}
.hide{
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
}

a {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="classic-price" class="hide"> Classic Price </p>

<a id="plus-button" href="#">Plus</a>

<a id="classic-button" href="#">Classic Button</a>

<a id="premium-button" href="#">Premium</a>
```

Comment: Oh finnaly it was right, thank you, this one is resolved but my code is still not working unfortunately

Comment: @EvanMounaud Can you share your whole code example here?

Comment: Actually this is on Wordpress so all the code I can share is there.. Maybe you can ask me for more informations ? Or if you want to take a look a the site ? I don't know if I can show link here ?

Comment: @EvanMounaud I edited my answer check it out

Comment: @EvanMounaud When you run my Code it works right?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not.. The error staying is : 
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function 

and it refer to the code :


$( "#classic-button" ).click(function() {

Comment: @EvanMounaud When you click on "Run code snippet" and then "Classic Button" you get error? I don't. Its working for me hmm

Comment: @EvanMounaud I mean the code here not on your Page :) When its Wordpress change the "$" sign into "jQuery" I edit my answer now

Comment: Okay to recap, here's my js code as you ask for and my button have the right class, and my table have the class "classic-price, plus-....' and the code you write into the tag, with the $ replace by jquery :<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Actually when I click on the buttons nothing happens into the console
I'm looking for run snippet because I don't know what it is

Comment: I type it in Visual studio and it looks like a parenthesis or something is missing, trying to fix it and then I'll try again and tell you, thank you anyway